# Anime where a young boy fed a robot a rock

Tags: story-identification, anime

In this anime a young boy tries to feed a robot lying on the ground with a big rock. I can only remember this scene and this is the only scene that I can 100% sure it happened.

Tried to search online with " young boy call robot with a flute ", after searching for years, and latest (today), quite a lot results show *Yamato Takeru*, which is totally not the one.

100% remember/accurate: he tried to talk to the robot but no response, he climbs onto the robot and feeds him a rock, the rock is as big as himself (the boy), he puts it into the robot's mouth and anticipate.

79 to 99% accurate: the robot did chew on the rock, they are resting on a mountain rocky area.

65% accurate: this robot will only move when someone plays the flute sound/music, or only by this young boy. Move by walking, not summon or others.

---

- The art might be 80s or 90s
- Can't remember whether watching on TV or renting VHS tape cassette
- young boy should be below 12 y.o.

Comment: Could it be Tranzor Z or Mazinger Z?